# Determine if a string index is part of a Regex match in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a regular expression such as `\$.*?\$` to select all text between pairs of `$`s, how would I tell if a string index matches is in one of these matches?

I could write my own function to do this, but this feels like something that would be built-in.

For example:

```js
let regex = /\$.*?\$/gm;
let myString = 'The $quick$ brown fox $jumps$ over the lazy $dog$';

myString[0] // false
myString[7] // true (middle of 'quick')
myString[15] // false (around 'brown' and 'fox)
myString[myString.length - 1] // true
```

I'm still a noob in regex, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: it seems that #regex is a cursed tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function in_match( pos, str, regex ) {
    let match;
    while ( ( match = regex.exec( str ) ) !== null) {
        // regex.lastIndex is the position after the last match.
        // And match[0] is the whole last match.
        if ( pos >= regex.lastIndex - match[0].length && pos < regex.lastIndex ) {
            // if pos is between the beginning and the end of the last match,
            // it is within a match, therefore, return true.
            return true;
        }
    }
    // pos is not within any match, so, return false.
    return false;
}

let regex = /\$.*?\$/gm;
let myString = 'The $quick$ brown fox $jumps$ over the lazy $dog$';

console.log( in_match( 0, myString, regex ) ); // false
console.log( in_match( 7, myString, regex ) ); // true (middle of 'quick')
console.log( in_match( 15, myString, regex ) ); // false (around 'brown' and 'fox)
console.log( in_match( myString.length - 1, myString, regex ) ); // true
```

Comment: @Keith, what do you mean? If you mean that `myStrung` has two `$dogs`, then it will not change anything.

Comment: Yes, looks good.  For some reason I though you had used match, not exec.  Not great reading code on mobile.. :)